# Need help with Data Comparison testing

Tags: test-data, data-quality

Is there a best tool for use to load up data and do a comparison large sets of data apart from Excel in a customizable way?

Comment: What type of data? Relational? Tree-based like XML? Graph-based? What kind of comparison? Values? Types?

Answer (score 1):

[Talend Open Studio for Data Quality](http://www.talend.com/products/data-quality/matrix) is a great tool for data comparison, data validation and lot of other data testing features. You can upload data from different type of sources into it and perform the checks.

But note that it is comparatively complex tool to begin with, so learning curve could be an important factor while choosing it.

Comment: I believe I cannot afford enterprise tools. At this point of time looking for something open source.

Comment: This is Open Studio. Not commercial.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that is very popular is RedGate, I have used it in the past with good results:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

How you are going to take data? Are you going to dumb the data from db or any external sources.

If you want to compare table data between tables in two different databases.use below tool

http://www.dbsolo.com/datacomp.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use shell scripting with a combination of sed, awk and md5 to parse and hash the data.